# How can i edit the error message box in CF-7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i had add some extra field on the CF-7 form everything work fine except the respond message box. im getting something like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JulGC.png

but i was hoping to get the error message only display next to my "Submit" Button.

is there anyway i can archive that? Im new to wordpress so im not really sure where can i start.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery validation. You can easily implement jquery validation in contact form 7

here is sample code for jquery validation.

```
$(".wpcf7-form").validate({
    rules: {
       yourname: "required",
     youremail: {
       required: true,
       email: true
      },
    },
       messages: {
        yourname: "Please include your name.",
        youremail: "Please include a valid email address.",
        yourmessage: "Please tell me how I can help you.",

    },
});
```

or PHP code,[Link contact form 7](https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/)

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
if ( 'your-email-confirm' == $tag->name ) {
    $your_email = isset( $_POST['your-email'] ) ? trim( $_POST['your-email'] ) : '';
    $your_email_confirm = isset( $_POST['your-email-confirm'] ) ? trim( $_POST['your-email-confirm'] ) : '';

    if ( $your_email != $your_email_confirm ) {
        $result->invalidate( $tag, "Are you sure this is the correct address?" );
    }
}

return $result;
}
```

or may use this plugin. [Jquery Validation For Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7/)

Hope this wiull helps you.